# 500 - Internal server error. IIS 7 using classic asp

Tags: events, iis-7, asp-classic, try-catch

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

Now showing error res-one. Please, how can I debug this `asp classic` language in PC?

Thanks!

Comment: What debugging tools do you have available - do you have Visual Studio? If so, check out this CodeProject article on [debugging ASP in VS2008](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28792/Debugging-Classic-ASP-VBScript-in-Visual-Studio-20) (and many more if you do a Google search for "Debug ASP").

Comment: Also, check Event Viewer for any error messages.

Comment: You should also check the IIS logfile. There should be a line logging this request with more information, depending on how logging is set up. When you get something from one of those sources, update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart ISS, check paths, full reload page (Ctlr+F5)...

Answer (score 0):

If you can, turn on logging in IIS and then check the log after you receive the 500 server error.  Also, you can try using the FireFox browser, sometimes it will tell you which line of your code is having a problem.